# Records not showing php

Tags: php, pdo

Hi im kinda new in php may i ask why i didnt show any records from my database
i hope someone can help me how to show the records of my database in html page
i double check everything cant still find the error
how can i fix this?
heres my source code of my work

```
            <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th class="font-weight-bold">No</th>
                            <th class="font-weight-bold">Branch</th>
                            <th class="font-weight-bold">Shift</th>
                            <th class="font-weight-bold">Nationality</th>
                            <th class="font-weight-bold">Classification</th>
                            <th class="font-weight-bold">Local Male</th>
                            <th class="font-weight-bold">Local Female</th>
                            <th class="font-weight-bold">Foreign Male</th>
                            <th class="font-weight-bold">Foreign Female</th>
                            <th class="font-weight-bold">Admissin Date</th>
                            <th class="font-weight-bold">Status</th>
                            <th class="font-weight-bold">Action</th>
                            
                            
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           <?php
                            if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
            $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
        } else {
            $pageno = 1;
        }
        // Formula for pagination
        $no_of_records_per_page = 15;
        $offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;
       $ret = "SELECT ID FROM tblstudent";
$query1 = $dbh -> prepare($ret);
$query1->execute();
$results1=$query1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$total_rows=$query1->rowCount();
$total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);
$sql="SELECT
 tblstudent.StuID,tblstudent.ID as sid,
 tblstudent.Branch,
 tblstudent.Shift,
 tblstudent.Nationality,
 tblstudent.Classification,
 tblstudent.LocalMale,
 tblstudent.LocalFemale,
 tblstudent.ForeignMale,
 tblstudent.ForeignFemale,
 tblstudent.DateofAdmission,
 tblstudent.Status
 
 LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page";
 




 $cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $row)
{   


              ?>   
                          <tr>
                           
                            <td><?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?></td>
                            <td><?php  echo htmlentities($row->Branch);?></td>
                            <td><?php  echo htmlentities($row->Shift);?></td>
                            <td><?php  echo htmlentities($row->Nationality);?></td>
                            <td><?php  echo htmlentities($row->Classification);?></td>
                            <td><?php  echo htmlentities($row->LocalMale);?></td>
                            <td><?php  echo htmlentities($row->LocalFemale);?></td>
                            <td><?php  echo htmlentities($row->ForeignMale);?></td>
                            <td><?php  echo htmlentities($row->ForeignFemale);?></td>
                            <td><?php  echo htmlentities($row->DateofAdmission);?></td>
                            <td><?php  echo htmlentities($row->Status);?></td>
                            <td>
                             <a href="edit-student-detail.php?editid=<?php echo htmlentities ($row->sid);?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
                             <a href="manage-students.php?delid=<?php echo ($row->sid);?>" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to Delete ?');" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"> <i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
                            </td> 
                          </tr><?php $cnt=$cnt+1;}} ?>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                    <div align="left">
    <ul class="pagination" >
        <li><a href="?pageno=1"><strong>First></strong></a></li>
        <li class="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
            <a href="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno - 1); } ?>"><strong style="padding-left: 10px">Prev></strong></a>
        </li>
        <li class="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
            <a href="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno + 1); } ?>"><strong style="padding-left: 10px">Next></strong></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="?pageno=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>"><strong style="padding-left: 10px">Last</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I hope someone can help me with this much appriciated

Comment: You should enable **error reporting**.  PHP will readily explain the problem in this code

Comment: Please read here: https://phpdelusions.net/basic_principles_of_web_programming . It will help with your first steps in programming